# Rewrite rule conversion to web.config

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, web-config

Could anyone tell me how what the conversion of the below rewrite would be for a web.config file?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(credits|content)/?$ switch.php?view=$1
```

Or if there is any online conversion tool that would be great.

Thanks

**EDIT**

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Would be:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you exactly how to convert the rules you have provided (I'm not great with .htaccess or web.config unfortunately), but there is a handy tool built into IIS Manager that enables you to convert .htaccess rewrite rules into IIS URL rewrite rules.

It's usage is described here:

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules

Answer (score 0):

This would convert 2 kind of incoming URLs like this:

```
http[s]://yoursite.com/credits => switch.php.view=credits
http[s]://yoursite.com/credits/ => switch.php.view=credits
http[s]://yoursite.com/content => switch.php.view=content
http[s]://yoursite.com/content/ => switch.php.view=content
```

Nb: this rule doesn't keep parameters in the URLs e.g.:

```
http[s]://yoursite.com/credits?param1=aa&param2=bb => switch.php.view=credits
http[s]://yoursite.com/credits/?param1=aa&param2=bb => switch.php.view=credits
http[s]://yoursite.com/content?param1=aa&param2=bb => switch.php.view=content
http[s]://yoursite.com/content/?param1=aa&param2=bb => switch.php.view=content
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but im still a little confused as to where exactly i would put these the examples i have seen look like the edit i have provided in my question.